# Auto lock after timeout in a .bat file

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I currently have two folders password protected on my Windows 7 system via a .bat file. Currently, I have to remember to lock it after I close the protected folder but I want to add a command line that will auto lock the folder 30 minutes after unlocking it (while retaining the option to manually lock it as well). I'd appreciate any help I can get!

The current .bat file is:

```
cls
@ECHO OFF
title Folder Private

if EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" goto UNLOCK
if NOT EXIST Private goto MDLOCKER

:CONFIRM

echo Are you sure you want to lock the folder(Y/N)
set/p "cho=>"
if %cho%==Y goto LOCK
if %cho%==y goto LOCK
if %cho%==n goto END
if %cho%==N goto END
echo Invalid choice.
goto CONFIRM

:LOCK

ren Private "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
echo Folder locked
goto End

:UNLOCK

echo Enter password to unlock folder
set/p "pass=>"
if NOT %pass%== **MY PASSWORD** goto FAIL
attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" Private
echo Folder Unlocked successfully
goto End

:FAIL

echo Invalid password
goto end

:MDLOCKER

md Private
echo Private created successfully
goto End

:End
```

Comment: Amazing how many people bought into this kind of script and think it actually protects/hides their files.

Comment: Thanks so much for your helpful contribution. I am completely aware that it doesn't protect your files. But for my needs, other than auto-locking, it does *exactly* what I want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm sorry Kristian, it doesn't "lock" anything either.
When you "lock" your "private" folder all you have really done is rename it, the renamed  folder is still accessible.

When you "unlock" the folder it simply renames it back to "private".  It hasn't gone anywhere and nothing is "unlocked".

It also tells the renamed folder to "pretend to hide yourself".

So it gives you the illusion that the folder is gone.

There is a simple setting on your computer (that most people use) that says "show me all those folders that are pretending to be hidden". With that setting in place those folders become completely visible again. Your private folder suddenly becomes visible again and will remain visible no matter how many times you run this program.

The folder has been renamed but is still completely accessible, nothing is hidden, nothing is locked, and your files aren't protected from anyone. This software is fooling you, not anyone else.

Sorry if this makes me seem as though I am being harsh with you, that is not my nature. But this program has been brought up here many times before, it gives you nothing but a false sense of protection, and you shouldn't be using it. Do yourself a favor and go buy a commercially available product that really does "lock" and/or "hide" your files.